# Tkinter - place_forget command

Tags: python, button, tkinter

If I have used the `place_forget` command in order to hide a button when switching frames, how can I bring the button back at a later stage in the program? Or would I have to recreate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to call `place` again. You do not have to recreate the widget as long as you keep a reference to the original widget.