# how do I implement the result of 2 buttons in 1 frame in a python program?

Tags: python, tkinter

hi I'm learning to create a program with python, but I have a button and frame problem, when I click button 1 it runs normally, but when I move to click button 2, the label and column on button 1 reappear in the click button 2

[Problem when click butoon 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lx7vA.png)

Here my code:

```
from tkinter import *
#import sqlite3
#import tkinter.messagebox

conn = sqlite3.connect("dbkom.db")
c = conn.cursor()

class Application:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Aplikasi Penjualan Komputer")
        # membuat frame utama aplikasi
        self.left = Frame(master, width=200, height=720, borderwidth=5, bg='white')
        self.left.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.top = Frame(master, width=800, height=60, bg='white')
        self.top.pack(side=TOP)

        self.right = Frame(master, width=800, height=700, borderwidth=5, bg='lightblue')
        self.right.pack(side=RIGHT)

        # Judul Program
        self.heading = Label(self.top, text="Aplikasi Penjualan Komputer", font=('calibri 16 bold'), bg= 'white')
        self.heading.place(x=200, y=20)

        # Button 1
        self.submit = Button(self.left, text="Data Pelanggan", width=20, height=2, bd = 0, bg='dimgrey', activebackground = 'lightgray',
                             activeforeground = 'black', fg = 'lightgray', command=self.data_pelanggan)
        self.submit.place(x=25, y=100)

        # Button 2
        self.submit = Button(self.left, text="Data Barang", width=20, height=2, bd = 0, bg='dimgrey', activebackground = 'lightgray',
                             activeforeground = 'black', fg = 'lightgray', command = self.data_barang)
        self.submit.place(x=25, y=150)
        self.submit = Button(self.left, text="Data Servis", width=20, height=2, bd=0, bg='dimgrey', activebackground='lightgray',
                             activeforeground='black', fg='lightgray')
        self.submit.place(x=25, y=200)
        self.submit = Button(self.left, text="Cetak Faktur", width=20, height=2, bd=0, bg='dimgrey', activebackground='lightgray',
                             activeforeground='black', fg='lightgray')
        self.submit.place(x=25, y=250)

    def data_pelanggan(self):
            # button1
            # Membuat user input
            self.noplg = Label(self.right, text="No Pelanggan", fg='black',  width=13, border=0, bg='lightblue')
            self.noplg.place(x=25, y=100)
            self.noplg_ent = Entry(self.right, width=20)
            self.noplg_ent.place(x=125, y=100)
            self.namaplg = Label(self.right, text="Nama Pelanggan",  fg='black', width=13, border=0, bg='lightblue')
            self.namaplg.place(x=25, y=120)
            self.namaplg_ent = Entry(self.right, width=20)
            self.namaplg_ent.place(x=125, y=120)
            self.notlpn = Label(self.right, text="No Telepon", fg='black', width=10, border=0, bg='lightblue')
            self.notlpn.place(x=25, y=140)
            self.notlpn_ent = Entry(self.right, width=20)
            self.notlpn_ent.place(x=125, y=140)
            self.alamat = Label(self.right, text="Alamat", fg='black', width=10, border=0, bg='lightblue')
            self.alamat.place(x=25, y=160)
            self.alamat_ent = Entry(self.right, width=20)
            self.alamat_ent.place(x=125, y=160)
            self.jkelamin = Label(self.right, text="Jenis Kelamin", fg='black', width=10, border=0, bg='lightblue')
            self.jkelamin.place(x=25, y=180)
            self.jkelamin_ent = Entry(self.right, width=20)
            self.jkelamin_ent.place(x=125, y=180)
            self.submit = Button(self.right, text="Input Data", width=10, height=1, bd=0, bg='yellowgreen',
                                 activebackground='lightgray', activeforeground='black', fg='black', command = self.dataplgget)
            self.submit.place(x=125, y=230)
            self.submit = Button(self.right, text="Clear Data", width=10, height=1, bd=0, bg='coral',
                         activebackground='lightgray', activeforeground='black', fg='black', command = self.cleardataplg)
            self.submit.place(x=210, y=230)
            self.submit = Button(self.right, text="Show Data", width=10, height=1, bd=0, bg='yellowgreen',
                         activebackground='lightgray', activeforeground='black', fg='black')
            self.submit.place(x=295, y=230)

    def dataplgget(self):
        self.val1 = self.noplg_ent.get()
        self.val2 = self.namaplg_ent.get()
        self.val3 = self.notlpn_ent.get()
        self.val4 = self.alamat_ent.get()
        self.val5 = self.jkelamin_ent.get()

        # cek input data gagal dan sukses
        if self.val1 == '' or self.val2 == '' or self.val3 == '' or self.val4 == '' or self.val5 == '':
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Warning", "Isi semua kolom")
        else:
            sql = "INSERT INTO 'data_pelanggan' (noplg, nm_plg, alamat, notlp, jk) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
            c.execute(sql, (self.val1, self.val2, self.val3, self.val4, self.val5))
            conn.commit()
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Sukses", "Pelanggan dengan nama " + str(self.val2) + " sudah dibuatkan")

    def cleardataplg(self):
        self.noplg_ent.delete(0, END)
        self.namaplg_ent.delete(0, END)
        self.notlpn_ent.delete(0, END)
        self.alamat_ent.delete(0, END)
        self.jkelamin_ent.delete(0, END)

    def data_barang(self):
            # button 2
            # User Input
            self.kdbrg = Label(self.right, text="Kode Barang", fg='black', width=10, border=0, bg='lightblue')
            self.kdbrg.place(x=25, y=100)
            self.kdbrg_ent = Entry(self.right, width=20)
            self.kdbrg_ent.place(x=125, y=100)
            self.nmbrg = Label(self.right, text="Nama Barang", fg='black', width=10, border=0, bg='lightblue')
            self.nmbrg.place(x=25, y=120)
            self.nmbrg_ent = Entry(self.right, width=20)
            self.nmbrg_ent.place(x=125, y=120)
            self.hrgbrg = Label(self.right, text="Harga Barang", fg='black', width=10, border=0, bg='lightblue')
            self.hrgbrg.place(x=25, y=140)
            self.hrgbrg_ent = Entry(self.right, width=20)
            self.hrgbrg_ent.place(x=125, y=140)
            self.stokbrg = Label(self.right, text="Stok Barang", fg='black', width=10, border=0, bg='lightblue')
            self.stokbrg.place(x=25, y=160)
            self.stokbrg_ent = Entry(self.right, width=20)
            self.stokbrg_ent.place(x=125, y=160)
            self.submit = Button(self.right, text="Input Data", width=10, height=1, bd=0, bg='yellowgreen',
                                 activebackground='lightgray', activeforeground='black', fg='black')
            self.submit.place(x=125, y=230)
            self.submit = Button(self.right, text="Clear Data", width=10, height=1, bd=0, bg='coral',
                                 activebackground='lightgray', activeforeground='black', fg='black', command=self.cleardatabrg)
            self.submit.place(x=210, y=230)
            self.submit = Button(self.right, text="Show Data", width=10, height=1, bd=0, bg='yellowgreen',
                                 activebackground='lightgray', activeforeground='black', fg='black')
            self.submit.place(x=295, y=230)

    def cleardatabrg(self):
        self.kdbrg_ent.delete(0, END)
        self.nmbrg_ent.delete(0, END)
        self.hrgbrg_ent.delete(0, END)
        self.stokbrg_ent.delete(0, END)


# membuat objek
r = Tk()
b = Application(r)

# mengubah logo
#r.iconbitmap('logokom.ico')

# mengatur resolusi dan tampilan awalan
r.geometry("800x400+180+180")

# preventif resolusi
r.resizable(False, False)

# akhir dari loop
r.mainloop()
```

I want, when the results from click button 1 are not carried away when I click button 2

Comment: Sorry maybe go back to the original. You need it all (except the database connection and the iconbitmap) to replicate the problem.

Comment: It isn't clear what you expect to happen when button 2 is clicked.

Comment: on the "data pelanggan" button I have 6 columns and on the "data barang" button I have 4 columns, when I finish input data on the "data pelanggan" button, on the next button [data barang] column increases to 6 columns, how to fix it?

Comment: Are you saying that you want the `jkelamin` and `jkelamin_ent` widgets  to *go away* or *disappear* when the "Data Barang" button is clicked?

Comment: I want to eliminate jkelamin and jkelamin_ent, when the "Data Barang" button is clicked. any idea mate?

Answer (score 0):

Either of these make the widgets *disappear*. I don't know the consequence of either. Maybe wait for someone else to comment/answer or ask a separate question asking for the consequence (or research/ read the docs).

```
        self.jkelamin.destroy()
        self.jkelamin_ent.destroy()
```

or

```
        self.jkelamin.place_forget()
        self.jkelamin_ent.place_forget()
```

---

[Tkinter - place_forget command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53776905/tkinter-place-forget-command)
[The Tkinter Place Geometry Manager](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm#Tkinter.Place.place_forget-method)